# Pausing the repair service

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I need to restart my nodes for a config change to take effect (reduced heap size) but I've read from the documentation that a node going up/down is one of the things that would make the repair service stop.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/online_help/services/repairServiceHowItWorks.html

Is there a way to pause a running repair service? One possibility is to shutdown the opscenterd process first because the documentation also says that the current status is persisted and the service will continue where it left off when the daemon is restarted. I'm just not sure whether it will work in my case because the daemon downtime will last for minutes instead of the usual seconds involved in a "restart". And of course, I'd prefer an official method to pause if there is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the repair service from opscenter while you do your procedure. I don't think there is a "pause" option where it will pick up where it left off.

Repair service creates 256 jobs per node in your cluster and runs them sequentially (or in parallel depending on config). If you stop the service and start it again it will just recreate the jobs and start over. No harm done.